# Rubocop: Assignment Branch Condition size for method is too high. How can I reduce the method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This block of code:

```
  def set_conversation
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
                                .match.origin_target.user_id == current_api_user.id ||
                    Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
                                .match.end_target.user_id == current_api_user.id
    head :forbidden if @conversation == false
  end
```

is returning the following rubocop offense:

```
Metrics/AbcSize: Assignment Branch Condition size for set_conversation is too high. [<1, 17, 5> 17.75/17]
```

I clearly understand the offense, but I'm having trouble refactoring the code to do the same task without adding too much unnecessary logic, especially because it's barely exceeding the suggested size. As a last resort, I may change the RuboCop config to ignore this block or to increase the limit, but first I want to try to solve it the intended way.

Comment: In addition to the proposed answer, which I am supportive of (specifically #2), this appears to be something that could also be composed into a single relational query although I cannot say for sure as I have no idea what `match` or the `*_target` methods are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start, which has the added benefit of setting `@conversation` to a conversation object, rather than a boolean value:

```
def set_conversation
  @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])

  user_ids = @conversation.match.tap { |m| [m.end_target.user_id, m.origin_target.user_id] }

  head :forbidden if user_ids.include?(current_api_user.id)
end
```

Although further improvements can probably be made by introducing some meaningfully named method to represent the concept that a user is allowed in a conversation, for example:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  def allowed_for?(user)
    match
      .tap { |m| [m.end_target.user_id, m.origin_target.user_id] }
      .include?(user.id)
  end
end

def set_conversation
  @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])

  head :forbidden conversation.allowed_for?(current_api_user)
end
```

This also allows `Conversation#allowed_for?` to be tested in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a complex lookup. One option is to extract this behaviour into a method on `Conversation`, e.g. `Conversation.lookup(params[:conversation_id], current_api_user)`

Another is to introduce a new service layer class or module, e.g.

`LookupConversation.lookup(params[:conversation_id], current_api_user)`

(there are likely other names you could choose to better reflect your application's business domain).